# PHP Laravel - Controller does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to PHP and Laravel. I am creating my first Laravel API where I am working with Post object.

In order to do so I use a PostController. I have created this controller using the `php artisan` command: `php artisan make:controller PostController --api`. This created a PostController class inside the `app\Http\Controllers`.

When I want to append this controller to the api routes using the `Route::resource` function I came across something strange. The course I followed told me to declare the controller like so: `Route::resource('posts', 'PostController');`. When testing the api `php artisan route:list` this gave the following error:`Target class [PostController] does not exist.`

Then I did some research and found an other way to declare the controller inside the api routes using:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\PostController;

Route::resource('posts', PostController::class);
```

This worked for me but I don't have any clue why the first declaration failed. I have looked inside my PostController class to see any typo's. But I couldn't find any:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostController extends Controller
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: You may have followed a course related to Laravel version less than 8. In Laravel 8 the route file (and defining routes) has changed a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is just like the exception says: it could not find the PostController in your declared namespace.

The reason for that highly depends on the Laravel version you are using. Laravel 8 removed the default namespacing to `App\Http\Controllers`, so if you are using Laravel 8 but have followed a tutorial for an earlier Laravel version, that might be the reason.

However, using the declaration using class imports is the better way to do it anyways, so I would stick with that.

Answer (score 1):

Since Laravel 8, there were some changes to the automatic controller namespace prefixing.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade#routing

You can continue to use the original auto-prefixed controller routing, see the 4th paragraph on the upgrade documentation. But the new way is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You should tell `Route::resource` method the controller's namespace. As you did in your second try.

If you wanna do it with your first attempt, you can tell it the required namespace

```
Route::resource('posts', 'App\Http\Controllers\PostController');
```

You can also set the namespace in your App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider:

```
public function boot()
{

    $this->routes(function () {
        Route::prefix('api')
            ->middleware('api')
            ->namespace('App\Http\Controllers\Api')
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    });
}
```